# Intersection of two list in salesforce apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two list T1 and T2 , T1 has 5 records and T2 has 10 records...
now i want to add t1 in another list t3 if the id doesnt exist in t3 .

Need little help in achieving this in apex

Comment: More information please, also post what code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

If you convert the List to a Set you can use the [contains(Object)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_contains) function and just iterate over the other list elements to find which ones are missing from the set and then just add them to the list t3.

To get a Set from a List you can use the constructor [new Set<T>(List<T>)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_ctor)

You could try something like the following where T is the type of your record (I'm assuming that you meant "if the id doesn't exist in t2" rather than "if the id doesn't exist in t3" in your question):

```
List<T> t1 = ...
List<T> t2 = ...
List<T> t3 = ...

Set<T> s2 = new Set<T>(t2);
for(T t : t1) {
    if(!s2.contains(t)) {
        t3.add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if T is an SObject, all the fields are considered not just the ID field which may or may not be what is wanted.